# Different fonts in Windows and Linux

Tags: fonts, cross-platform

I'm using lualatex to create PDFs with lyrics. Here is an example slide with one verse:

```
\documentclass[12pt,sansfont,16x9]{elpres}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{psli}[Psalm 119:60]
\LARGE
Tot U loop ek, op u hoop ek, \\ op u wette gee ek ag; \\ en ek hou wat U getuig het \\ vol van liefde‿en stil ontsag. \\ 'k Voeg my stil na u bevele \\ - mag ek dié maar nooit vergeet! \\ HEER, U weet dit - al my weë \\ is voor U wat alles weet.
\end{psli}
\end{document}
```

Running `lualatex doc.tex` in Linux gives me correct output:

[image: Correct output]

Log:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2017.6.20)  13 MAR 2018 17:02
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2017/01/29 2.80001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using write cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gene
ric)(using read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /h
ome/dolf/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2017-02-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontl
oader-2017-02-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.027”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.203 seconds
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elpres/elpres.cls
Document Class: elpres 2018/01/24 class for plain electronic presentations
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc(load luc: /usr/local/texlive
/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-regular.luc))
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2016/10/11 v3.9 Extensive control of page headers and footers
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip43
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip44
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip45
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip46
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip47
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip48
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip49
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip50
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip51
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2017/06/17 v1.0d Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pagecolor/pagecolor.sty
Package: pagecolor 2017/05/29 v1.0i Provides thepagecolor (HMM)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)))))
\GPT@outputbox=\box26

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nopageno/nopageno.sty
Package: nopageno 1989/01/01 no page numbers (DPC)
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
(load luc: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsa
ns12-regular.luc)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(14.22636pt, 466.62521pt, 19.91692pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(14.22636pt, 244.69373pt, 22.76219pt)
* \paperwidth=500.7685pt
* \paperheight=281.68228pt
* \textwidth=466.62521pt
* \textheight=244.69373pt
* \oddsidemargin=-58.04362pt
* \evensidemargin=-58.04362pt
* \topmargin=-83.04362pt
* \headheight=0.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=10.2pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count90
\scratchdimen=\dimen111
\scratchbox=\box27
\nofMPsegments=\count91
\nofMParguments=\count92
\everyMPshowfont=\toks16
\MPscratchCnt=\count93
\MPscratchDim=\dimen112
\MPnumerator=\count94
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count95
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks17
)(load luc: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lms
ans10-bold.luc)(load luc: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic
/fonts/otl/lmsans17-regular.luc) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test
.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 2336 strings out of 494481
 100000,106986 words of node,token memory allocated
 368 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:31,3:13,4:10,5:41,6:192,7:108,8:4,9:26,10:7,11:1
 6407 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 19 fonts using 1250183 bytes
 36i,5n,45p,263b,177s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans17-regular.ot
f></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf
>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 7355 bytes).

PDF statistics: 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Running `lualatex doc.tex` in Windows gives me the wrong font, and no unicode characters:

[image: Incorrect output]

Log:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2018.3.13)  13 MAR 2018 17:04
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
[\directlua]:1: module 'luaotfload-main' not found:
    no field package.preload['luaotfload-main']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
Error in luaotfload: reverting to OT1
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elpres/elpres.cls
Document Class: elpres 2018/01/24 class for plain electronic presentations
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmr on input line 54.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OT1lmr.fd. on input line 54.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 54.

)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
) (c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.st
y
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
)
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers

\f@nch@headwidth=\skip43
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip44
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip45
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip46
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip47
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip48
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip49
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip50
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip51
)) (c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 225.

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.de
f
File: luatex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pagecolor/pagecolor.st
y
Package: pagecolor 2017/05/29 v1.0i Provides thepagecolor (HMM)

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.s
ty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.s
ty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.st
y
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.st
y
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)))))
\GPT@outputbox=\box26

(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nopageno/nopageno.sty
Package: nopageno 1989/01/01 no page numbers (DPC)
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmss on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OT1lmss.fd. on input line 8.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/lmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(14.22636pt, 466.62521pt, 19.91692pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(14.22636pt, 244.69373pt, 22.76219pt)
* \paperwidth=500.7685pt
* \paperheight=281.68228pt
* \textwidth=466.62521pt
* \textheight=244.69373pt
* \oddsidemargin=-58.04362pt
* \evensidemargin=-58.04362pt
* \topmargin=-83.04362pt
* \headheight=0.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=10.2pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


(c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.m
kii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count90
\scratchdimen=\dimen111
\scratchbox=\box27
\nofMPsegments=\count91
\nofMParguments=\count92
\everyMPshowfont=\toks16
\MPscratchCnt=\count93
\MPscratchDim=\dimen112
\MPnumerator=\count94
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count95
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks17
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/lmss/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/lmss/m/n' instead on input line 10.

[1

{c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}
Missing character: There is no ‿ (U+203F) in font cmr17!
Missing character: There is no é (U+00E9) in font cmr17!
Missing character: There is no ë (U+00EB) in font cmr17!
] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 2359 strings out of 494480
 100000,106986 words of node,token memory allocated
 351 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 47 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:12,3:13,4:10,5:47,6:192,7:107,8:4,9:26,10:7,11:1
 6424 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 18 fonts using 533987 bytes
 36i,5n,45p,263b,177s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
<c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
r12.pfb><c:/Users/dolf/skuifiemaker/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 23534 bytes).

PDF statistics: 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

So it complains about not finding certain characters in the `Computer Modern Roman` font, but it's supposed to use `Latin Modern Sans Serif` like in the Linux example.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: because of the error at the begin: `module 'luaotfload-main' not found`.  There is something  broken in the luaotfload package.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I find these logs quite hard to read...

Answer (score 2):

There were some missing packages in texlive under Windows. The fix was simple:

```
tlmgr install luaotfload lm
```

- luaotfload lets lualatex load Open Type Fonts
- lm is the package containing the Latin Modern font family

Now the output is the same on both platforms.